# How can we get exactly 2 digits after the decimal point in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, decimal, rounding

For Example,

0.14 instead of 0.1445436

9.94 instead of 9.94476

9.99 instead of 9.99996544

8.90 instead of 8.9

Comment: You should read the manual next time - `.toFixed(2)` returns a string with the number rounded to 2 points.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum unfortunately `.toFixed(2)` doesn't add padding for a value like `0.2`.  -- **oops yes it does, sorry**

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yep I was fumbling with the console but you're 100% right.  I guess I don't code with that API very often.

Comment: @Pointy +1 for admitting you're wrong instead of deleting and hiding.

Comment: @DanielBank Totally not a duplicate, it off by 1 whole decimal place! XD smh

Answer (score 0):

```
 n = 0.14
nDec = n.toFixed(2)
```

You need to throw the toFixed() method at the number. The number in parens is the number of digits from teh decimal.

Comment: Duplicate questions should be closed